# how to read new(even read) emails from inbox using java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to schedule the email service where i want to read new emails(may also be read after every one hour) now i am able to read IMAP email inbox from gmail using java mail. Now its the big part of finding new emails in my inbox and to parse then. My working code for feching and parsing email is as below.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        try {
            IMAPSSLStore store = (IMAPSSLStore)session.getStore(IMAP);
            store.connect( host, userName, password ) ;
            Folder folderInbox =store.getFolder(IMAP_FOLDER);
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
//            FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
//            Message[] arrayMessages= folderInbox.search(ft);
            Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) arrayMessages[i];
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                message.writeTo(bos);
                bos.close();
                SharedByteArrayInputStream bis =new SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
                MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
                bis.close();

                String contentType = cmsg.getContentType();

                String messageContent = "";

                String megSubject = cmsg.getSubject().toString().trim();

                if(megSubject.contains(configurationStringToCheckSubject.trim())){
                    if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                            || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                        Object content = cmsg.getContent();
                        if (content != null) {
                            messageContent = content.toString().trim();
                            messageContent=messageContent.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
                            messageContent=messageContent.replaceAll("\n", "");

//                            System.out.println("normal message is**********\n"+messageContent);
                            status=compareContents(messageContent, configurationStringToCheckBody);
                            if(status){
                                return megSubject;
                            }

                        }
                     }else if (contentType.contains(IMAP_CONTENT_TYPE)) {

                        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) cmsg.getContent();

                        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                            if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {

                                String messageContent1=getText(part) ;
                                messageContent+=messageContent1;
                                messageContent=messageContent.replaceAll("\n", "");
                                status=compareContents(messageContent, configurationStringToCheckBody);
                                if(status){
                                    return megSubject;
                                }                         
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What's your question?  I don't understand what you're asking, if anything.